# Algorithm to determine if audio is music

Tags: algorithm, audio

I'm not entirely sure this is the correct stack exchange subsite to post this question to, but...

I'm looking for an algorithm that I can use to determine with a decent amount of certainty if a given piece of audio is music or not. Just a boolean result is fine, I don't need to know the key, bpm or anything like that, I just need to be able to determine if it appears to be music (as opposed to speech). Programming language is irrelevant, but I'll end up converting it to Python.

Comment: even humans will disagree on whether a given sound is music or not :-/

Comment: This is a *very hard problem*.

Comment: If the only other option is speech, you might get away with a simple frequency check, as a lot of it will usually be outside the spectrum of a human voice.

Comment: @Wrikken: this will still not be "simple".

Comment: I would ask at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ and IF YOU'RE LUCKY you might find some grad student there who is working on something that can do this.  I know it seems like what you're asking for is simple; but you're really asking for a lot.  People can get their PhDs off of providing what you just asked for.

Comment: If you ever solve this problem, I'd like to run it on my university's "Center for 21st-century music" to see what happens.

Comment: Wonder what John Cage would think (people argue, violently, whether he composed music or not; for an extreme example, see [4'33"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4'33%22) )

Comment: @Wrikken: Your solution will generate 100% false negatives for [A cappella](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_cappella) music.

Comment: I had a hunch that this would be a tough nut to crack. I think I'm gonna try and get by with a combination of beat detection, Fourier based frequency analysis and educated guesswork.

Comment: Not necessarily, as people singing & talking are possibly different frequency-ranges (I'd hate to listen to someone talking in C6), and mind you, I didn't say it was a definite solution, it was a starting point.

Comment: @Wrikken: Possibly...,- except maybe for RAP music, where talking and singing are not very well separable :-) Still agree,- it would be something to start from...

Comment: @0x69: Or (depending on viewpoint) it would identify A Cappella as "not musical" with 100% accuracy. Some would say the same applied to Rap. Call me narrow minded if you will, but neither fits *my* ideas of "musical" very well..

Comment: I'm gonna go ahead and call Jerry Coffin narrow-minded, as it was apparently allowed.

Comment: Although it's not an algorithm, a way to get some training data tags could be to use a system like Gracenote to identify genre, etc. Algorithm-wise, I'd start with FFTs.

Answer (score 13):

In a phrase, [Fourier analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_analysis).  Look at the power of different frequencies over time.  Here's [speech](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/st/Spectrogram_Speech.html), and here's [violin playing](http://www.knowledgerush.com/kr/encyclopedia/Physics_of_music/).  The former shows dramatic changes with every syllable; the 'flow' is very disjoint and could be picked up by an algorithm which took the derivative of the different frequency bands as a function of time.  In paradigmatic music, on the other hand, the transitions are much smoother and the tones are purer (less 'blur' in the graph).  See also the ['spectrogram' wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrogram).

Comment: Yes, that's called spectral flux.  It can be useful for determining how "dynamic" a sound might be perceived to be.  However spectral flux alone won't permit you to do speech/music discrimination reliably; you'll need other features too.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason this question has attracted a large number of really bad answers.

Use [pyAudioAnalysis](https://github.com/tyiannak/pyAudioAnalysis/wiki).  Also, Google "audio feature analysis".

On its surface, this sounds like a hard problem, but there's been an explosion of great work on classifiers in the past 20 years, so many well-documented solutions exist.  Most classifiers today usually can figure this out with an error rate of only a few percent.  Some classifiers can even figure out [what genre of music it is](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1699270/).

Most current algorithms for doing this break down into detecting a bunch of statistical representations of the input audio (features), and then doing a set of [automatic classifications](http://www.nyu.edu/classes/bello/ACA_files/8-classification.pdf) of the inputs based on previous training data.

[pyAudioAnalysis](https://github.com/tyiannak/pyAudioAnalysis/wiki) is one library for extracting these features and then training a kNN or other mixed model based on the detected features.  There are many more comparable libraries, such as [Essentia](http://essentia.upf.edu/documentation/) for C++.  Essentia also has Python bindings.

[An Introduction to Audio Content Analysis: Applications in Signal Processing and Music Informatics](http://a.co/c4ZeoOx) is a good introductory book.

Comment: pyAudioAnalysis is very poorly documented/ maintained.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is set up a few Karplus Strong resonance rings  and through the audio through them, and just monitor the level of energy in each ring

if it is Western music,  it is pretty much all tuned to 12-TET, ie  logarithmic 12 tone scale based around concert pitch A4@440Hz

so just pick 3 or 4 notes equally spaced through the octave eg C5, (omit C# D D#) E5 (omit F F# G) G#5 (omit A A# B)

and at least one of those rings will be flaring regularly -- whichever key the music is in,  it's probably going to hit one of those notes quite a lot

ideally do it for a bunch of notes, but if you need this real-time it can get a bit heavy feeding your audio simultaneously into 50 rings

alternatively you could even use a pitch detector and catalogue recorded pitches, and look at ratios of log(noteAfreq):log(noteBfreq) see whether they are arranging themselves into low order fractions like 3:4 += 0.5%.   but I don't think anyone has built a decent polyphonic pitch detector -- it is practically impossible.

Melodyne might have pulled it off

If it's just a vocal signal you can e-mail me.

Comment: What is a "resonance ring"?  What does Karplus-Strong have to do with detecting the existence of frequencies?

Answer (score 0):

Look for a small "First differential" over a sequence of FFTs that are in the range of music tones (ie: 1024 samples per chunk run through FFT, then plot   chunk1-chunk0,chunk2-chunk1,...).  As a first approximation, this should be enough to detect simple things.

This is the sort of algorithm that could be tweaked forever, even in genre-specific ways.  Music itself is generally periodic as well, so coming up with a way to run FFTs over the FFTs.  And the idea to look for a consistent twelfth root of two spread of outstanding frequencies sounds really plausible.

I bet you were hoping to find this sitting in an free Python library for you to simply drop a file into.  :-)